# Laravel 5.7 cant use assets with Vue in blade template

Tags: laravel, vue.js, assets

Hello I have Laravel version 5.7.24. I have problem with import `app.js` to blade template.
I have `app.js` in `resources/js/app.js`, this same file is other location: `public/js/app.js`

In welcome.blade.php I add:

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        Hello
        <example-component></example-component>
        <articles></articles>
    </div>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

I created articles component in `resources/js/components/articles.vue`:

```
<template>
    <div>
        Hello
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "Articles"
}
</script>
```

Now Laravel return me error:

> Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component
>   correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name"
>   option.

Because `asset` refers to the `public/js/app.js`

I read in this [article](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-7-resources-directory-changes), taht Laravel removed assets foler. So I added assets folder and my file structure looks like this:

[image]

but still Laravel references the file `public/js/app.js`.

**How I can import srcipt (resources/js/app.js) to my welcome.blade.php file ?**

**Edit:**

my `resources/js/app.js` file:

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('articles', require('./components/Articles.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

When I change script from (in `welcome.blade.php`):

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

> I have error: GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/js/app.js
>   net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: are you importing that component in `app.js`? please share the file `resources/js/app.js`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Yes, I edit my query

Comment: the app.js in public folder is the compiled code that you should use in your blade template, you could generate it from `resources/aj/app.js`using `npm run dev` or `npm run watch`

Comment: <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script> its Fine. Might problem with         <example-component></example-component> you have used in your code but did not created a this component

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I use `npm run watch`. So I should import to `welcome.blade.php` script from `public` folder ?

Comment: yes you should use that in public folder

Comment: the problem is in `<example-component></example-component>` since it's not registered in your app.js

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Yes, beacuse I change `example-component` to `articles` component.

Comment: so try to remove `<example-component></example-component>` from your blade template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a mistake in this line of your app.js:

```
Vue.component('articles', require('./components/Articles.vue').default);
```

Try removing `.default` from here, and see if the component is registered correctly when you build again ([`npm run dev`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix#running-mix)).

---

Side note: `<articles>` should contain a hyphen like `my-articles`, `v-articles`, or something else.

> When using a component directly in the DOM (as opposed to in a string
> template or single-file component), we strongly recommend following
> the W3C rules for custom tag names (all-lowercase, must contain a
> hyphen). This helps you avoid conflicts with current and future HTML
> elements.
>
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Component-Names